# gcc -o stdlib.h syntax error c Hacking the Art of Exploitation

Tags: c, gcc, include, syntax-error

I am working out of the 2nd edition of Jon Erickson's "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" using a VM (virutalbox) to run the LiveCD it came with (Ubuntu 7.04). In section 0x272 "Using the Heap", the author explains the malloc() and free() functions using an example on pages 77-79.

The code for the heap_example.c is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
        char *char_ptr;
        int *int_ptr;
        int mem_size;

        if(argc < 2)
                mem_size = 50;
        else
                mem_size = atoi(argv[1]);

        printf("\t[+]allocating %d bytes of memory on the heap for char_ptr\n",mem_size);
        char_ptr = (char *)malloc(mem_size);

        if(char_ptr == NULL){  //Error checking,in case malloc() fails
                fprintf(stderr,"Error:could not allocate heap memory.\n");
                exit(-1);
        }

        strcpy(char_ptr,"This is memory is located on the heap.");
        printf("char_ptr(%p)-->'%s'\n",char_ptr,char_ptr);

        printf("\t[+]allocating 12 bytes of memory on the heap for int_ptr\n");
        int_ptr = (int *)malloc(12);

        if(int_ptr == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error:could not allocate heap memory.\n");
                exit(-1);
        }

        *int_ptr = 31337;
        printf("int_ptr (%p)--> %d\n",int_ptr,*int_ptr);

        printf("\t[-]freeing char_ptr's heap memory...\n");
        free(char_ptr);

        printf("\t[+]allocating another 15 bytes for char_ptr\n");
        char_ptr = (char*)malloc(15);

        if(char_ptr == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error:could not allocate heap memory.\n");
                exit(-1);
        }

        strcpy(char_ptr,"new memory");
        printf("char_ptr (%p)-->'%s'\n",char_ptr,char_ptr);

        printf("\t[-]freeing int_ptr's heap memory...\n");
        free(int_ptr);
        printf("\t[-]freeing char_ptr's heap memory...\n");
        free(char_ptr);
}
```

However, when I type the following instructions stated in the book into my terminal window:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gcc -o heap_example heap_example.c
```

It spits out the following error message regarding syntax errors in my stdlib.h

```
In file included from heap_example.c:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:469: error: syntax error before "int32_t"
/usr/include/stdlib.h:471: error: syntax error before '*' token
/usr/include/stdlib.h:475: error: syntax error before '*' token
/usr/include/stdlib.h:476: error: syntax error before '}' token
/usr/include/stdlib.h:479: error: syntax error before "int32_t"
```

Here is where the error seems to take place in my stdlib.h (lines 467 - 479)

```
struct random_data
    {
        int32_t *fptr;        /* Front pointer. */
        int32_t *rptr;        /* Rear pointer. */
        int32_t *state;       /* Array of state values. */
        int rand_type;        /* Type of random number generator. */
        int rand_deg;         /* Degree of random number generator. */
        int rand_sep;         /* Distance between front and rear. */
        int32_t *end_ptr;     /* Pointer behind state table. */
    };

extern int random_r (struct random_data *__restrict __buf,
                     int32_t *__restrict __result) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
```

Then when I try to run it:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./heap_example
```

I get this:

```
bash: ./heap_example: No such file or directory
```

I believe that heap_example.c is the first file in the book that includes the stdlib.h (all the prior examples used only stdio.h, so I had no issues).

Will changing the stdlib.h file fix this problem? If so, how might I go about correcting these errors? I figured I should fix this issue ASAP as the rest of the code examples in this book will probably start to include stdlib.h

Thanks!

Comment: Try inserting `#include <stdint.h>` before `#include <stdlib.h>` .

Comment: It works! Thanks so much.

Comment: @whjm how might I go about debugging errors like these next time?

Comment: That looks more like an error in `stdlib.h`. It should actually `#include` all required other std headers. I'd check that and if it does, there seems to be a different problem which has just be covered now - bad juju.

Comment: @user1234 - According to the error message it sounds like the compiler does not know what `int32_t` is. So just `#include` the correct `.h` file which defines `int32_t`.